# variable declaration inside for loop without braces causes error

Tags: java, variable-declaration

I taught braces in for loop are only necessary when you have more than one statement. I have the following code

```
public static void someMethod(int[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < arr.length;i++)
        int t = arr[i]; // this gives an error
}
```

The above code in eclipse gives an error saying the left hand side of an assignment operator must be a variable. In netbeans, it says variable declaration not allowed there. But i don't know why. When i add braces, i don't get the error. That is the following code runs well.

```
public static void anotherMethod(int[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < arr.length;i++)
    {
        int t = arr[i]; // this works well
    }
}
```

NOTE: The logic of my code is irrelevant. I mean the statement alone is useless but i just noticed that error while i was still writing my code.

Comment: You get an error because the JLS says that this is invalid. You know that such code would be useless, and would most probably indicate a bug, so you should be happy that the compiler warns you about it.

Comment: this behavior is correct, your assumptions are wrong, and never leave off the braces for any reason it is terrible that it is even allowed

Comment: i know the code is useless, that is why i added the note. I have not read the java specification but all books says you only need braces when you have more than one statement. The uselessness of the code should be my problem, not the compiler's

Comment: Yes, but books are not as precise and picky as the JLS. They do approximations to let the newbie reader understand the general rule.